# Implementing provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to implement provider at the top of my app, but am getting an error: "positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found". I have tried different implementations but then I get runtime error "build function returned null". Is there something wrong with the below implementation?

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider<UserModel>(
      builder: (context) => UserModel(),
      return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Profile Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Profile'),
    ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

My UserModel looks like this:

```
class UserModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  String uid;
}
```

Full MyHomePage code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection(Provider.of<UserModel>(context).uid)
            .document('testuser')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                new Image.network(
                  snapshot.data['photourl'].toString(),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                new BackdropFilter(
                    filter: new ui.ImageFilter.blur(
                      sigmaX: 6.0,
                      sigmaY: 6.0,
                    ),
                    child: new Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.9),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                      ),
                    )),
                new Scaffold(
                    appBar: new AppBar(
                      title: new Text(widget.title),
                      centerTitle: false,
                      elevation: 0.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    drawer: new Drawer(
                      child: new Container(),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    body: new Center(
                      child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new SizedBox(
                            height: _height / 12,
                          ),
                          new CircleAvatar(
                            radius: _width < _height ? _width / 4 : _height / 4,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data['photourl']),
                          ),
                          new SizedBox(
                            height: _height / 25.0,
                          ),
                          new Text(
                            snapshot.data['name'],
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: _width / 15,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          new Padding(
                            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: _height / 30,
                                left: _width / 8,
                                right: _width / 8),
                          ),
                          new Divider(
                            height: _height / 15,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              rowCell(
                                  snapshot.data['totalquestions'], 'Answers'),
                              rowCell(
                                  '£ ${int.parse(snapshot.data['totalquestions']) * 2}', 'Earned'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          new Divider(
                              height: _height / 15, color: Colors.white),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Can you post code for `new MyHomePage(title: 'Profile')`. There must be a extra parameter which is not required.

Comment: @VrushiPatel sure, just added above

Comment: First, I don't see notifyListeners() in your model.

Second, "positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found" should be showing an error in your IDE when you mouse over the constructor that has the problem. Which one is it? --- You can usually hunt positional parameter errors down by finding the constructor that has *anything* after the * that isn't a named parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to return a MaterialApp. You need to set the MaterialApp as a child of Provider, not return it:

```
Provider<UserModel>(
builder: (context) => UserModel(),
child: MaterialApp(      // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Here
title: 'Profile Demo',
theme: new ThemeData(
primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
),
```